# A strange Qt IDE label appear on the left of the Qt window

Tags: qt, qt-creator

[image]

does anybody get this problem, a new label 'hello world' appear on the left. I tried to remove Qt and re-install but 'hello world' is still there.

Comment: ...and can you click on it, and does anything happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the "HelloWorld" plugin which comes with Qt Creator, but is disabled by default.

You can enable/disable it by going to "Help > About Plugins..." (You have to check the "Show all" checkbox in the upper right corner to see it).

[image: Installed plugins]

Unchecking the checkbox in the "Load" column and restarting Qt Creator should remove the label.